# Creating a HTTP proxy with user and pass with Squid

Tags: linux, http, squid

I want to know if with *Squid* I can use as a proxy with basic auth, to use with cURL for example:

```
curl -vvv "https://ifconfig.me" -x user:password@localhost:8000
```

Where localhost is the Squid instance.

Is it possible with Squid and HTTPS websites?

Comment: yes and end-user question are off-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
htpasswd -bc /etc/squid/passwords user password
```

squid.conf

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated

http_port 3128
```